# fractional numbers in java android?

Tags: java, android, apk

How do I write a fractional equation in layout of apk android  like this ;

[image: fraction]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's probably LaTeX (pronounced Lahtech or Laytech), a C-based rendering engine, at work.

I suggest you look at projects like [AndroidMath](https://github.com/gregcockroft/AndroidMath) if you want to use this in your own android apps.